# Como alterar um atributo de um select sem ser pelo option value?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tenho um select renderizado na view com dados recuperados em um banco de dados. Na tabela em questão `estado`, tenho os atributos `id`, `siglaEstado` e `descricaoEstado`. No caso estou usando o `id` no value da `option` para realizar alterações no banco, como no código:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label for="estado"><span>*</span>Estado:</label>
   <select id="estado" class="form-control" name="estado" required>
       <option selected>Selecione seu estado</option>
       <?php foreach($estados as $estado){?>
           <!-- Tentei adicionar esse data-uf para renderizar a opção -->
           <option data-uf="<?php echo $estado['siglaEstado'];?>" 
              value="<?php echo $estado['idEstado'];?>"> 
              <?php echo $estado['descricaoEstado'];?> 
           </option>
        <?php }?>
   </select> 
</div>
```

E tenho um script que preenche automaticamente o endereço de acordo com o cep inserido, onde a api retorna um `json` contendo a UF do estado.

```
$("#cep").focusout(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+$(this).val()+'/json/unicode/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(resposta){
            $("#logradouro").val(resposta.logradouro);
            $("#complemento").val(resposta.complemento);
            $("#bairro").val(resposta.bairro);
            $("#cidade").val(resposta.localidade);
            //Aqui eu tentei recuperar o valor no data-attr inserido no html
            $("#estado").data("data-uf").val(resposta.uf);
            $("#numero").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Tentei colocar um `data-` no option mas não consegui preencher o estado.

Como eu faço para preencher esse select de acordo com essa sigla retornada na api sem ter que alterar o value do meu option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode selecionar a opção que contém o data-uf igual a resposta e torná-lo selected. Tente:

`$("#estado option[data-uf="+resposta.uf+"]").attr("selected", true);`

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!